# Redirect on Global.asax not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I have empty website with blank `index.html` file (only mandatory HTML tags). And wanted to try out redirect through `Global.asax` file, but either the `Global.asax` file is not working for some reason or my redirect is badly coded. Here is the code on `Global.asax`:

```
namespace redirectURL
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string responseURL = "http://live.com/blog";

            if (Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("://loc.test.com"))
            {
                Response.Redirect(responseURL);
            }
        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for help in forward.

Comment: Is the .html extension being processed by .NET module in your IIS ?

Comment: In Global.asax, I always use HttpContext.Current.Response/Request/Session

Comment: This is what I have set, so I am not sure if missed something out. Created empty web project, added blank html to it and set as start page, then added global.asax and added my code. On IIS I've set new website marked physical path to my blank web project and virtual path to loc.test.com. Registered loc.test.com in host file.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your code in the `Application_BeginRequest` function and see if it gets reached.

Comment: Well it seems like it does not see Global.asax file. Breackpoints were not hit, on Application_Start I had console.writeline and debug.writeline and those seem to be left out as well. 

Any ideas why it is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating blank(empty web application) website I used "web forms application" and added same code as above to my global.asax file and removed all the content files that I did not need(leaving global.asax, web.config, references and properties). And end result was as needed - empty project with only redirect on global.asax file.